# more concise url route pattern in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, routes

everyone.

I'm using sinatra to build a web application. In the api part, there are so many routes that starts with a common prefix, for example:

```
get '/v1/command_1' do; end
get '/v1/command_2' do; end
get '/v1/command_3' do; end
get '/v1/command_4' do; end
get '/v1/command_5' do; end
```

I'm wondering how can I avoid all these '/v1' prefix? Can I just define once in one route, and in the other routes, I can start with '/command_1' or something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used it before, but there's an extension from the sinatra-contrib project that will let you nest like that.

http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/namespace.html

Then you could do something like this:

```
namespace '/v1' do
  get '/command_1' {}
  get '/command_2' {}
  # etc
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
get '/v1/command_:command' do |command|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: the routes is not that simple, sorry for my imprecise description. The api routes can get quite nested, for example '/v1/users/1' and '/v1/teams/1'.

Comment: Sorry, still don't see it. The point is, where you want a variable, you put a colon and a name. `/v1/users/1` looks quite different from `/v1/command_1`, so I'd put it as two different patterns - unless there's something you're not telling me :)

Comment: Hi, Amadan! It's not about if this method is right or wrong, It's just I think mportiz08's answer is better. Thanks anyway!